Validation of Approximate Solution
I approximated the solution for equation $P(x,\varepsilon)=x^3+\varepsilon x +2\varepsilon^2$ by a leading order using the successive approximations method.
I defined $F=x^3, \quad G=-\varepsilon x-2\varepsilon^2$ and got a single root of $x\cong\sqrt[3]{-2\varepsilon^2}$.
Questions

What assumptions should be validated for the solution's consistency?

Solving the same equation using the undetermined gauges method provides a different gauge function, indicating that the gauge computed by successive approximations is incorrect. Why did this method lead to the wrong gauge?


The solved equation is from the book "Perturbations Theory and Methods" by James A. Murdock.

This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.
A little bit surprized by your result, I solve the cubic equation assuming $\epsilon>0$. The result, given by the hyperbolic solution is
$$x=2i\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon }{3}}\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(-3 i
    \sqrt{3\epsilon }\right)\right)$$ Expanded as a series
$$x=i \sqrt{\epsilon }+\epsilon +\frac{3}{2} i  \epsilon ^{3/2}
-4 \epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon^{5/2}\right) \tag 1$$
Plugging in the equation, this gives
$$x^3+\epsilon x +2\epsilon^2=-\frac{105}{4} i \epsilon ^{7/2}+O(\epsilon^4)$$
Using
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n\,\epsilon^{\frac n 2}$$ and Taylor series gives $a_1=\pm i$. Choosing $a_1=i$ gives $a_2=1$, $a_3=\frac{3}{2} i$, $a_4=-4$ and so on. This is the same as $(1)$.
All of the above was numerically checked.
For example, if $\epsilon=\frac 1{100}$, $(1)$ gives $$x=\frac{6}{625}+\frac{203 i}{2000}=0.0096000\,+0.1015000\, i$$ while, converted to decimals, the corresponding root is
$$x=0.0096415\, +0.101385\,i$$

Partial answer, regarding consistency check:

Magnitude Comparison: Compare the magnitudes of successive terms.
Convergence Check: Ensure that the series converges. If the terms do not decrease in magnitude, the series may not be valid.

